# Confusing button options for user

Tags: buttons, placement, information

We are working on a design that allows users to select from a few designs and then print.

The issue is that there are 3 options :

1. Print with Regular printer
2. Save as image and print with special print on plastic printer 
   ( Requires you to save the image and load it in a software that cannot be synced with the app )
3. Save as image and send it to a printing center or store it in your PC , whatever.

My issue is that users with plastic printers might think that the print button would open the plastic printer dialog box ( that cannot be done ).

I`m thinking having a text under the buttons to inform but I am not sure it conveys the message well.

[image]

Comment: Is image format the same for any image printing option?

Comment: Yes it is. Same size and format.

Comment: So, what is special with your system that you separate saving image for printing on plastic?

Comment: Is this for a mobile app, desktop, web?

Answer (score 4):

### Leave a separate note!

Not below the "Save as image" button or **specific** to it.

Users with **regular printers** might want to just save the design **as an image** too!

If the text goes **below** the button, it conveys that it is **specific to it**, so users would think that using this option "Save as image" is only **specific to users with Plastic Printers** (or printing centers...).

What if I am a user with a **regular printer** but I want to save the design as an image? Should I use this option or that has a specific format only for users with plastic printers? That's what could go in users minds.

***I think what you are trying to achieve is guiding users with Plastic Printers (and printing centers...) that they need to follow certain steps to achieve their goal.***

Leave a separate note (not under a specific button) to guide users with plastic printers (and printing centers...) that they need to save the image first then load it...etc. Mainly a note tells them how to achieve their goal.

Answer (score 1):

### Updated:

**Use icons and better copies**.

The anatomy of each button will also help. So, if your primary users are going to use a regular printer, **highlight it**.

Use two buttons:

1. "Print" with a dropdown (little down arrow at the right of the button), so the user will know that **it will not printing in the moment he push it**.  The dropdown will list: "Regular Print" and "Special Printing". If you push the Special Printing, it will show a tooltip telling the user that if he wants to plastic print it, he needs to save the image and blablabla, the steps to make it happen. A little modal or tooltip will work.
2. "Save as..." with a follpy disk; the user will save the file to the computer, but **he will know that the file is plastic printing proof**.

Comment: 40$+40$+10% = 90%, the left 10% for gutter purposes :D Obv. this is a **approximation**

Comment: You may notice in the comments under the question that saving the image for plastic printing is not special. It just saves it. Your answer suggests adding two buttons (button and icon) that does the same exact thing (serves the same exact goal).

Comment: Wow, didn't notice, gonna edit the answer right now.

Comment: I have just change the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'd talk to your user like you would with a person.

- "Print with regular printer"
- "Save as image to print on Plastic Printer"

If needed (to make sure it's even more fool proof), you could add the third button too, the one that would do exactly the same thing, but it could help with user's confusion:

- "Save as image"